# how to display nodejs file (including html) on website

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs file (including HTML code). How can I display the result on the website? I am using EC2 ubuntu. I have two js files, one is `index.js`, the other is `server.js`

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

It gives me the error:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
>   "/home/ubuntu/server/views"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `views` directory in order to make the render happen properly.

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where did you set that? Before your `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` or after?

Comment: It has to be coming after your `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` statement. Please check.

Comment: Can you please try these two options individually and see if one of them works or not?, i) `app.set('views', './');` (OR)  ii) `app.set('views', './server/views');`?